# What kind of Intent is used for choosing between applications, and how to listen for it?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to create a kind of file manager to allow the user to upload files (from the file manager) to the internet.

I would like to understand how this application would be triggered.

For example:
When using Gmail and pressing the add-attachment button, Android shows me two applications (the Gallery and FileExpert) to pick the content from.

- How is this accomplished?
- What kind of Intent is brodacasted (if an intent is used)?
- What kind of object are the Gallery and FileManager that are able to be invoked
  by pressing the add-attachment button?

Comment: You can simply call a Context menu after click on attach button...

Comment: @Piyush Gupta thank you, but i would like to have a behaviour as the one described, that when the user clicks add-attachment on Gmail my application is invoked.

Comment: Yes... I understand.. Like in some case when we are running the app in device and if process are being used in same project then after click on any button in app it opens the Context menu with Two Application name....isn't it???

Comment: @PiyushGupta that is the idea...

Comment: I edited your question and title to clarify that you are not trying to find out how to attach files in an email, but rather how the selcting Intent works. Revert if I have misunderstood.

Comment: @Lisa So do you want to same functionality??

Comment: @Jave thansk, that is what I need.

Comment: @PiyushGupta thanks please see the comment from Jave and my reply. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, this is achieved using Intents. In particular, the calling app (Gmail in your example) sends an intent for uploading one or multiple files. For choosing a file, the intent is [Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/2teqoEuWQUA).

To add your app to the list of applications handling this intent, you need to specify it in your manifest. According to [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html), it would look something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_GET_CONTENT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

see the following snippet

```
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

            File fileToEmail=new File("FIle Path");             


            Uri updf = Uri.fromFile(fileToEmail);//adding pdf uri
             uris.add(updf);                 

                final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);              
                emailIntent.setType("image/*");               
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {});
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, caseObj.getCaseTitle());
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("mailto:"));                    
                 emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
                activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Send mail..."));
```

Comment: @PSoftware Sainath thank you, but i would like to have a behaviour as the one described, that when the user clicks add-attachment on Gmail my application is invoked